# Jack port not detected in Dell Inspiron 15 3000

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, dell, headphones

I recently installed Ubuntu on my laptop, but I can't connect headphones. I tried to reinstall pulseaudio, but it didn't work, It just doesn't show the jack port on configurations, on pulseaudio program it shows like this.

[image: pulse audio]

Even with this option enabled the sound keeps coming from the speakers. I tried to enable the speaker in the BIOS, however it's still the same. In the configurations now that I deactivated the speakers, it just doesn't find any device port.

[image: configurations]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: the latest 22.04